# ASP.NET Identity & Posting JWT to Another Site

Tags: asp.net, wordpress, oauth, jwt, identityserver4

I'm trying to implement "single sign-on" so that users of my ASP.NET site can jump to a WordPress site and automatically have their account created. There is a plug-in for WordPress called JWT Authenticator that will send unknown users to a URL you provide and then you can POST back a JWT with enough information for the plug-in to do it's thing and automatically login the user over there.

I can see how one might accomplish this just by generating a JWT using something like JOSE and then in javascript posting the token over, but I was hoping to capitalize on any existing code in the ASP.NET Identity/OAuth/JWT packages to manage the heavy lifting (especially the posting of the JWT).

Is that a standard "flow" for OAuth? I suppose in that case the ASP.NET site is sort of an Identity Server but the documentation for that sort of thing seems to suggest a structure way out of proportion for "make a JWT & post it back there".

Any ideas what subset of functions exist in the Identity & OAuth libraries for doing this?

Thanks!

James